# apache settings block php exec() from executing

Tags: php, apache, executable-jar

I have apache 2.4.12 and php 5.5.21 installed on my machine. I’m trying to get a java jar file to execute using php exec (). When I have the php program in a folder outside the apache htdocs, it opens up and executes the jar file without a problem. When I run the same exact program out of the apache (in the htdocs) folder, nothing executes and the web browser just stays in a loading stage (the browser hangs up and eventually will just time out). I think I’ve seen every example out there and can’t pinpoint where the issue is. It’s certainly a permissions issue; I just need to get pointed in the right direction.

Echo shell_exec ("whoami"); gives me "ntauthority/system. When I go to services and change the apache log on to administrator nothing happens. I have read and execute permissions on the jar file in trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a shared host, you may have to talk to your hosting provider.

If you have access to your `httpd.conf` in Apache, edit the file, CTRL+F and make sure any `safe_mode` value is set to `Off`. If you don't see a `safe_mode` setting anywhere in the file, add this line:

`php_admin_flag safe_mode Off`

Make sure the "O" is capitalized! [(Source)](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=102958)

If that isn't the issue, then make sure your `disabled_functions` in your `php.ini` file does not contain `exec`.

If *that* isn't the issue, try to see if your `php.ini` contains a `safe_mode` variable. If not, add this line:

`safe_mode = Off`

Again, if the file has a `safe_mode` variable, set it to `Off`!

Comment: i added "php_admin_flag safe_mode Off" to the bottom of my "C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf" file. I didnt see any "safe_mode" in my httpd.conf file for apache. In my php.ini file the disable functions is set at"disable_functions ="    i restarted the apache server and nothing still, its still hanging up in the web browser?

Comment: Did you try and see if `safe_mode` in your `php.ini` was set to `Off`?

Comment: the php.ini has this line "sql.safe_mode = Off" 
i also added "safe_mode = Off" underneath it and restarted apache and nothing still

Comment: Hmm, well you said the `jar` file outside of the htdocs folder works... Can you `chdir()` into your htdocs directory and *then* call `exec()`? It may be it can't find your program because it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: the jar file is inside htdocs for both programs, the difference is when i run a php program that isn't inside htdocs (i use rapid php 2015 with the built in web server feature when running outside of htdocs) it executes the jar file.

Comment: the php exec() statement

exec("java -jar C:\Apache24\htdocs\Java\hm_reports\dist\hm_reports.jar 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);


when i run this php program out of cmd 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\Java\hm_reports\java_run.php

it executes just fine and my jar comes up......

Comment: better yet, what would be the proper way to give apache the permissions to execute to jar file?? i thnk thats the problem

Comment: You could give `Everyone` permissions to read/execute your jar file, if that works, then it's a permission issue.

Comment: Kenny, i already had given everyone permission to the jar file

Answer (score 0):

i had apache installed as a service through command prompt and the jar file wasnt launching. When i uninstalled apache as a service, and manually ran "httpd.exe". the jar files came up and executed. I could only execute them on that machine, i still had issues trying to execute them on client side machines. Ive gone the route of using java webstart and it seems to be easier to deploy and use. thanks